# Is there any way to know the possible values of a parameter when it's not in the documentation?

Tags: weather-api

I'm trying to build a weather website using https://www.weatherapi.com/ , and I have a problem with one of the data fields.

When accessing the "condition" object, there is a field called "text" which tells the current condition of the weather in the respective city. What I am trying to build, is to change the background of the web site on the basis of what the condition is.

> ! My problem is, the possible values of the "text" field is not documented. I've been searching for a while now, and I can't understand what to do. Do I scrape my idea? Or is there some other alternative to getting a-hold of this information?
> This is my first ever project, so thanks for being patient with me.